# Ansible ec2_asg - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ansible

I am working with Ansible `ec2_asg` module with `Ansible 2.1.2.0`. When I am trying to create a Autoscaling group, I get the following error:

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_sYlKBr/ansible_module_ec2_asg.py\", line 832, in <module>\n    main()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_sYlKBr/ansible_module_ec2_asg.py\", line 821, in main\n    create_changed, asg_properties=create_autoscaling_group(connection, module)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_sYlKBr/ansible_module_ec2_asg.py\", line 471, in create_autoscaling_group\n    for tag in as_group.tags:\nTypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE"}
```

We dig into the module `ec2_asg`, and it is failing here:

[Ansible ec2_asg](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/stable-2.1/cloud/amazon/ec2_asg.py#L471)

```
    for tag in as_group.tags:
        have_tags[tag.key] = [tag.value, tag.propagate_at_launch]
        if tag.key not in want_tags:
            changed = True
            dead_tags.append(tag)
```

And my ansible task is:

```
- name: Configuring Auto Scaling Group and perform rolling deploy
  ec2_asg:
    region: "ap-southeast-1a"
    name: "MY-ASG"
    vpc_zone_identifier: [ "{{ services_1_subnet_id }}", "{{ services_2_subnet_id }}" ]
    launch_config_name: "{{ service_group }}-{{ current_datetime }}"
    health_check_type: "{{ health_check_type }}"
    health_check_period: "{{ health_check_period }}"
    desired_capacity: "{{ min_instances }}"
    replace_all_instances: yes
    replace_batch_size: "{{ replace_batch_size }}"
    min_size: "{{ min_instances }}"
    max_size: "{{ max_instances }}"
    wait_for_instances: yes
    wait_timeout: 600
    tags:
      - Name: "{{ service_group }}"
      - deploy_colour: "{{ deploy_colour }}"
      - Type: "ABC"
      - Env: "{{ env }}"
    state: present
  register: asg_result
```

Please assume all variables are already defined and they are correct.

The ASG already have the tags.

Comment: What is `item` in `Type: "{{ item.type }}"`? Do you loop over some list?

Comment: Yes. I loop over a list of items which is like `- { name: 'XYZ', type: 'ABC'}`

Comment: If you loop, there should be item's value in the error message, like: `failed: [localhost] (item={u'type': u'ABC', u'name': u'XYZ'}) => {"failed"...` and you don't specify `with_items` in your playbook excerpt.

Comment: I am looping over `with_items` only.

Comment: Please add more context to the question (how do you use `with_items`), because, as I said, if you do use it, error message should be different.

Comment: I suddenly started to have the issue with ansible 2.0.1, can't figure out what changed

Answer (score 0):

I spent quite lot of time in figuring this out. The solution to this problem for me was that, My ASG was having Target Groups as well as Classical ELBs.

There are some changes in the AWS APIs due to which, if you are connected to Target Groups to the ASG, it will not work.

Hence, the solution is remove your ASG with Target Groups and then try. It worked for me.

Cheers!

Comment: To clarify, are you saying that if the ASG is part of a target group, you cannot update the tag for the ASG in the AWS API?

Comment: I was able to add the tags via the aws cli, so I believe the issue is with ansible.  I've created an issue for it here: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/23234